# SQL Query for the mentioned task

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which has data below

```
ID       Name     Designation    
25       Vikas      SE
26       Chetu      TL
27       Mahesh     TL
28       Raghu      Mgr
29       Darshan    Mgr
30       Santhosh   Mgr
```

Now i need to add one more column to table to achieve result like this.

```
ID       Name     Designation  Appearance  
25       Vikas     SE               1
26       Chetu     TL               1
27       Mahesh    TL               2
28       Raghu     Manager          1
29       Darshan   Manager          2
30       Santhosh  Manager          3
```

can anyone help me out to write query to achieve above task

Comment: Can anyone edit the question to get the table structure

Comment: Mgr or manager , anything is fine. I need to get appearance column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), where you `PARTITION BY` Designation:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Designation,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Designation ORDER BY ID) AS Appearance
FROM theTable
```